# HTMX and Playwright: Button press does nothing

Tags: playwright, htmx

I have a very simple [htmx](//htmx.org) example which works manually, but fails via Playwright:

You can test it here: https://thomas-guettler.de/htmx-snippets/load-fragment-via-hx-get.html

````
import os

from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright

def run(playwright):
    browser = playwright.chromium.launch(headless=False, devtools=True)
    context = browser.new_context()
    page = context.new_page()
    page.goto("https://thomas-guettler.de/htmx-snippets/load-fragment-via-hx-get.html")
    page.click("text=load second button")
    page.click("text=Reload Parent OOB")
    page.dblclick("text=This should be the end")
    # ---------------------
    context.close()
    browser.close()


os.environ['DEBUG'] = 'pw:api'
with sync_playwright() as playwright:
    run(playwright)```
````

Loading the second button works, but "Reload Parent OOB" fails.

What could be the reason?

```
2021-03-19T06:39:17.114Z pw:api navigating to "https://thomas-guettler.de/htmx-snippets/load-fragment-via-hx-get.html", waiting until "load"
2021-03-19T06:39:17.317Z pw:api   navigated to "https://thomas-guettler.de/htmx-snippets/load-fragment-via-hx-get.html"
2021-03-19T06:39:17.534Z pw:api   "domcontentloaded" event fired
2021-03-19T06:39:17.547Z pw:api   "load" event fired
2021-03-19T06:39:17.554Z pw:api waiting for selector "text=load second button"
2021-03-19T06:39:17.591Z pw:api   selector resolved to visible <button hx-swap="outerHTML" hx-get="second-button.htmx">load second button</button>
2021-03-19T06:39:17.599Z pw:api attempting click action
2021-03-19T06:39:17.599Z pw:api   waiting for element to be visible, enabled and stable
2021-03-19T06:39:17.635Z pw:api   element is visible, enabled and stable
2021-03-19T06:39:17.635Z pw:api   scrolling into view if needed
2021-03-19T06:39:17.636Z pw:api   done scrolling
2021-03-19T06:39:17.638Z pw:api   checking that element receives pointer events at (117.19,18.48)
2021-03-19T06:39:17.643Z pw:api   element does receive pointer events
2021-03-19T06:39:17.643Z pw:api   performing click action
2021-03-19T06:39:17.653Z pw:api   click action done
2021-03-19T06:39:17.653Z pw:api   waiting for scheduled navigations to finish
2021-03-19T06:39:17.656Z pw:api   navigations have finished
2021-03-19T06:39:17.660Z pw:api waiting for selector "text=Reload Parent OOB"
2021-03-19T06:39:17.688Z pw:api   selector resolved to visible <button class="htmx-settling" hx-get="reload-parent-oob.…>Reload Parent OOB</button>
2021-03-19T06:39:17.692Z pw:api attempting click action
2021-03-19T06:39:17.692Z pw:api   waiting for element to be visible, enabled and stable
2021-03-19T06:39:17.716Z pw:api   element is visible, enabled and stable
2021-03-19T06:39:17.717Z pw:api   scrolling into view if needed
2021-03-19T06:39:17.717Z pw:api   done scrolling
2021-03-19T06:39:17.719Z pw:api   checking that element receives pointer events at (120.14,18.48)
2021-03-19T06:39:17.727Z pw:api   element does receive pointer events
2021-03-19T06:39:17.727Z pw:api   performing click action
2021-03-19T06:39:17.730Z pw:api   click action done
2021-03-19T06:39:17.730Z pw:api   waiting for scheduled navigations to finish
2021-03-19T06:39:17.743Z pw:api   navigations have finished
2021-03-19T06:39:17.746Z pw:api waiting for selector "text=This should be the end"
2021-03-19T06:39:18.179Z pw:api   "networkidle" event fired
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/guettli/projects/lala-env/src/lala/lala/playwright/test.py", line 24, in <module>
    run(playwright)
  File "/home/guettli/projects/lala-env/src/lala/lala/playwright/test.py", line 16, in run
    page.dblclick("text=This should be the end")
  File "/home/guettli/projects/lala-env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/playwright/sync_api/_generated.py", line 6437, in dblclick
    self._sync(
  File "/home/guettli/projects/lala-env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/playwright/_impl/_sync_base.py", line 103, in _sync
    return task.result()
  File "/home/guettli/projects/lala-env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/playwright/_impl/_page.py", line 611, in dblclick
    return await self._main_frame.dblclick(**locals_to_params(locals()))
  File "/home/guettli/projects/lala-env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/playwright/_impl/_frame.py", line 387, in dblclick
    await self._channel.send("dblclick", locals_to_params(locals()))
  File "/home/guettli/projects/lala-env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/playwright/_impl/_connection.py", line 36, in send
    return await self.inner_send(method, params, False)
  File "/home/guettli/projects/lala-env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/playwright/_impl/_connection.py", line 47, in inner_send
    result = await callback.future
playwright._impl._api_types.TimeoutError: Timeout 30000ms exceeded.
=========================== logs ===========================
waiting for selector "text=This should be the end"
```

Comment: What's the fail?

Comment: @hardkoded I added more details

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with playwright, but I had a similar problem with chromedp (https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/chromedp/chromedp). I believe the problem is that the click happens before HTMX has completed its operations (see https://htmx.org/docs/#request-operations). Using `sleep` makes this race condition less likely to occur, but it is more robust to wait until the `htmx-added` css class is no longer present.

Pseudocode:

```
Click("thing1")
WaitVisible("thing2")
WaitNotPresent(".htmx-added")
Click("thing2")
```

Comment: Do you had similar issues? AFAIK this was solved in either Playwright or htmx, so that the manual sleep (or other work-around) is not needed any more.

Comment: Yes, it seemed very similar, except I used last version of htmx (1.9.2), chromedp, and an html link (not button). My code clicked an element with the hx-get attribute, but nothing happened (..well it worked "sometimes"). My guess is that chromedp discovered the link in the DOM and clicked it too early, before the event handling in htmx was ready. The problem was solved by checking for "htmx-added".

It could of course be something else than your issue. It's long time ago, and I don't know about playwright.

Answer (score 0):

I found a "solution", but I don't like it:

```
import os
import time

from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright
def run(playwright):
    browser = playwright.chromium.launch(headless=False, devtools=True)
    context = browser.new_context()
    page = context.new_page()
    page.goto("https://thomas-guettler.de/htmx-snippets/load-fragment-via-hx-get.html")
    page.click("text=load second button")
    time.sleep(0.1) # <<<< ===================== If I wait here, it works ===
    page.click("text=Reload Parent OOB")
    page.dblclick("text=This should be the end")
    # ---------------------
    context.close()
    browser.close()


os.environ['DEBUG'] = 'pw:api'
with sync_playwright() as playwright:
    run(playwright)
```

I would like to avoid this waiting here.

Is this a bug in Playwright or htmx?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like an issue with htmx, adding delay to the second click helps:

```py
page.click("text=Reload Parent OOB", delay=100)
```

Perhaps htmx does something between mouse down and mouse up so that the delay matters. Dario opened [an issue](https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/issues/5888) in Playwright on this.